# Modal Pop Out Print problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I am trying to print a pop out model but for some reason clicking print button won't call anything. My Jscript, Css Code and HTML is as follows

**Jscript**

```
    <script>
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("outborder"));

    var modThis = document.querySelector("#printSection .modifyMe");
    modThis.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" new"));

    window.print();
}

function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    $printSection.innerHTML = "";

    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
}
</script>
```

**My HTML Code**

```
    <?php
foreach ($orders as $order):
    $products = unserialize($order->order_cart);
    ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $order->order_id ?>" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="outborder" style="
    border: 1px solid #000;
">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <center><img src="http://www.webuyback.com.au/images/headera4.PNG" width="580px"/></center>
                <hr />
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Order Details</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                            <center><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Order ID</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $order->order_id ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Order Date</td>
                                        <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($order->order_date)) ?></td>
                                   </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 208px;">Customer Name</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $order->firstname . " " . $order->lastname ?> 
                                   </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Payment Method</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $order->payment_method ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Delivery Method</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $order->delivery_method ?></td>  </tr>

                            </table></center>
                        </div>


                <div class="modal-body">        
                    <table border="2" class="table table-striped container">
                        <tr class="txt_bold">
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Device</td>
                            <td>Condition</td>
                            <td>IMEI</td>
                            <td>Price</td><br />
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                        $total = 0;
                        foreach ($products as $product):
                            ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="<?php echo $product['image'] ?>" height="75" width="50"></td>
                                <td><?php echo $product['name'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $product['condition'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $product['imei'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo CURRENCY_SYMBOL.$product['price'] ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            $total += $product['price'];
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </table>
                    <div style="float:right;"><b>Total <?php echo CURRENCY_SYMBOL.$total?></b></div>
                    <br />
                    <center><img src="http://www.webuyback.com.au/images/signa4.png" width="580px" /></center>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnprint">Print</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php
endforeach;
?>
```

**My CSS is as follows**

```
@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible;
  }
  #printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

   .modal-content {
        display:block;
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Jayden

Comment: Why do you use "java" tag here?

Comment: Hi, the Tag was suggested by Stackoverflow system. Apologies if it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of JS errors on your page. Kindly check your dev tools. You could also check the snippet below. Note though that this won't print successfully if `print` is called by the iframe.

```js
document.getElementById("btnprint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("outborder"));

    window.print();
}

function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    $printSection.innerHTML = "";

    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
}
```

```css
@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible;
  }
  #printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

   .modal-content {
        display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="outborder" style="
    border: 1px solid #000;
">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <center><img src="http://www.webuyback.com.au/images/headera4.PNG" width="580px"/></center>
                <hr />
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Order Details</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                            <center><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Order ID</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $order->order_id ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Order Date</td>
                                        <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($order->order_date)) ?></td>
                                   </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 208px;">Customer Name</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $order->firstname . " " . $order->lastname ?> 
                                   </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Payment Method</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $order->payment_method ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Delivery Method</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $order->delivery_method ?></td>  </tr>

                            </table></center>
                        </div>


                <div class="modal-body">        
                    <table border="2" class="table table-striped container">
                        <tr class="txt_bold">
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Device</td>
                            <td>Condition</td>
                            <td>IMEI</td>
                            <td>Price</td><br />
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                        $total = 0;
                        foreach ($products as $product):
                            ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="<?php echo $product['image'] ?>" height="75" width="50"></td>
                                <td><?php echo $product['name'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $product['condition'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $product['imei'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo CURRENCY_SYMBOL.$product['price'] ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            $total += $product['price'];
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </table>
                    <div style="float:right;"><b>Total <?php echo CURRENCY_SYMBOL.$total?></b></div>
                    <br />
                    <center><img src="http://www.webuyback.com.au/images/signa4.png" width="580px" /></center>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnprint">Print</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
<div id="printSection"></div>
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you very much for your reply. I did the changes but for some reason the print button does not work. When I test the snippet here, it works flawlessly but when I made changes onto my actual file, clicking the button doesn't do anything? DO I need to paste the Javascript in mabe some specific part of the code?

Comment: You need to paste the scripts at the end of the body.